# Trying to run plex media server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, linux, media-server

Hi I'm trying to run Plex on my Raspberry Pi 1st gen rev B, but it does not seem to be starting. I have followed [this guide](https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-plex-server/) and looked at others that look the same and can't see what the issue is. It seems to be installing ok and does not give any error messages after `sudo service plexmediaserver start`, I just get no webif when I put the IP and port into my web browser.

I am running the latest Raspbian Stretch on the Pi. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the print out of the status

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service plexmediaserver status

* plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-11-30 20:10:19 UTC; 3min 42s ago
  Process: 4781 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver "/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Serv
  Process: 4777 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -
 Main PID: 4781 (code=exited, status=132)   
Nov 30 20:10:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 20:10:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 20:10:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The error indicates that the main process (not the ExecPre) has failed. In my case, running the command directly:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Server`

Resulted in an error `Illegal Instruction`

I checked /proc/cpuinfo and /proc/meminfo and verified with the help of [the hardware history page on elinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware) that the pi I had chosen was an old Model B with 512MB RAM.

A comment at [one of the installation tutorials](https://thepi.io/how-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-plex-server/) noted similar symptoms on a 256MB Model B, so I suspect this hardware isn't capable of running this version of Plex.

A comment on [the Plex discussion forum](https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/224278/raspberry-pi-1-as-pms)says:

> the new PMS versions require Arm7

and a [further post](https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/302175/server-is-not-started-on-rpi-model-b) confirms this.

My solution is to go and get a newer pi and try it. Unfortunately the newer Pi was just a model B+ and showed exactly the same symptoms even after

`sudo apt-get remove --purge plexmediaserver* sudo apt-get install plexmediaserver-installer`

There is an error during installation which was also there before, but I'm not sure if it is important:
`rm: cannot remove '/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service.d/override.conf': No such file or directory`

I still believe the solution is a newer Pi, hope that helps you as well.